# How to apply easing animation function on view in Android

Tags: android, animation, easing, easing-functions

I want to apply a translate `animation` on an Android `view` (button) using a custom `interpolator` where the easing function is:

```
public static float easeOut(float t,float b , float c, float d) {
    if ((t/=d) < (1/2.75f)) {
       return c*(7.5625f*t*t) + b;
    } else if (t < (2/2.75f)) {
       return c*(7.5625f*(t-=(1.5f/2.75f))*t + .75f) + b;
    } else if (t < (2.5/2.75)) {
       return c*(7.5625f*(t-=(2.25f/2.75f))*t + .9375f) + b;
    } else {
       return c*(7.5625f*(t-=(2.625f/2.75f))*t + .984375f) + b;
    }
}
```

I have an example that uses the custom interpolator like this:

The interpolator is:

```
public class HesitateInterpolator implements Interpolator {
    public HesitateInterpolator() {
    }

    public float getInterpolation(float t) {
        float x = 2.0f * t - 1.0f;
        return 0.5f * (x * x * x + 1.0f);
    }
}
```

and is used like this:

```
ScaleAnimation anim = new ScaleAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
anim.setInterpolator(new HesitateInterpolator());
```

My question is: 
What are these values `b`, `c`, `d` for?

Comment: There is an alternative approach.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/39125948/2219600

Answer (score 24):

FYI: for people who just want an ease interpolator you can just use `myAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());`

Comment: Or: myAnimation.setInterpolator(mContext, android.R.interpolator.accelerate_decelerate);

Answer (score 15):

I made a library which can solve this problem. [AndroidEasingFunctions](https://github.com/daimajia/AnimationEasingFunctions)

[image]

Comment: Great library! I do feel it's necessary to note that you should not import Android's ObjectAnimator and AnimatorSet, but com.nineoldandroids's, so it's also necessary to 
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'

Comment: Thanks for the library though! :) Just add some documentation on the usage or what to look out for.

Answer (score 12):

**1,2,3 go**

1. Create a custom cubic bezier curve using this [awesome site](https://matthewlein.com/ceaser/). And get the control points for the curve. Between 0,0 and 1,1
2. `Interpolator customInterpolator = PathInterpolatorCompat.create(cpX1,cpX2,cpY1,cpY2)`
3. Add this customInterpolator to any of your animation.

Added a [gist](https://gist.github.com/amalChandran/6abc2f7cbd2643492e3fc45e9c3f4819).
Some [more here](https://medium.com/@preciselyamal/custom-interpolators-for-animation-on-android-using-pathinterpolatorcompat-a104486d2fb2#.oyij8ndpc).

Answer (score 11):

According to [Robert Penner's Easing Functions](http://www.robertpenner.com/easing/), as stated [here](https://github.com/danro/jquery-easing/blob/master/jquery.easing.js):

t: current time, b: begInnIng value, c: change In value, d: duration

If you want to implement your custom Interpolator, you have to make something like this:

(this would be the implementation for the `easeInOutQuint`)

```
public class MVAccelerateDecelerateInterpolator implements Interpolator {

    // easeInOutQuint
    public float getInterpolation(float t) {
        float x;
        if (t<0.5f)
        { 
            x = t*2.0f;
            return 0.5f*x*x*x*x*x;
        }
        x = (t-0.5f)*2-1;
        return 0.5f*x*x*x*x*x+1;
    }
}
```

Edit:
to implement the easing function you need some math knowledge, considering that the `getInterpolation` method gets only the t parameter, from 0.0 to 1.0.

So basically you need to develop a y(t) function, with t from 0 to 1, and with y values from 0 to 1, as shown below:

[image]

What you change is the curve to get from 0 to 1 (in the image the green line is the linear one, for example). You need to 'normalize' the easing functions to remain in the (0, 1) x (0, 1) square, as you can see in my `easeInOutQuint` implementation.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer, but how did you get this functions you mentioned in your answer?.. How to convert the functions that Robert wrote to java functions in factor of t only ?

Comment: Thank you very much for you clarification, can you provide me with reference to learn how to  normalize function to function from 0-1 function ?

Comment: Sorry but is matter of math knownledge... i've made it by me. You can use a visual plot tool to simplify the job, such as http://rechneronline.de/function-graphs/

Comment: Sorry for many questions I ask :(, If I have equation like this:  easeInOutQuad: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2*t*t + b;
return -c/2 * ((--t)*(t-2) - 1) + b;
},  .. How can I make the equation only have only one variable,, y = f(x) .. what do you use for the constants

Comment: The functions for easeInOutQuad are:
(x*2)^2/2 for t<0.5
-((x-1)^2)*2+1 for t>0.5

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution, made possible by a recent addition to android's support library:
https://gist.github.com/ebabel/8ff41cad01e9ce1dd9ce

and an example in use:

```
public static void expand(final View v) {
    v.measure(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    final int targetHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();

    if ( v.getHeight() != targetHeight ) {
        // Older versions of android (pre API 21) cancel animations for views with a height of 0 so use 1 instead.
        v.getLayoutParams().height = 1;
        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        Animation a = new Animation() {
            @Override
            protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
                v.getLayoutParams().height = interpolatedTime == 1
                        ? ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                        : (int) (targetHeight * interpolatedTime);
                v.requestLayout();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean willChangeBounds() {
                return true;
            }
        };

        a.setInterpolator(EasingsConstants.easeInOutQuart);
        a.setDuration(computeDurationFromHeight(v));
        v.startAnimation(a);
    } else {
        Log.d("AnimationUtil", "expand Already expanded ");
    }
}

/**
 * 1dp/ms * multiplier
 */
private static int computeDurationFromHeight(View v) {
    return (int) (v.getMeasuredHeight() / v.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density) * DURATION_MULTIPLIER;
}
```

Comment: gist link not working.. Is EasingsConstants a custom class?

Comment: @RikvanVelzen sorry about that, the link was removed from another answer so I deleted the gist. It is a custom class with a bunch of constants defining values from easings.net like so: public static final Interpolator easeInOutQuad = PathInterpolatorCompat.create(0.455f, 0.03f, 0.515f, 0.955f);