# android scaleanimation with custom Interpolator make easing effect

Tags: android, android-animation, material-design, scaleanimation

I created ScaleAnimation and  added my custom Interpolator.i try to recieve slide animaton right to left.this is a my source

```
 public class HesitateInterpolator implements Interpolator {
    public HesitateInterpolator() {}
    public float getInterpolation(float x) {

        return (float) (6 * Math.pow(x, 2) - 8 * Math.pow(x, 3) + 3 * Math.pow(x, 4));
    }
}
```

and this is a my animation source code:

```
 ScaleAnimation anim = new ScaleAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        anim.setDuration(100);
        anim.setInterpolator(new HesitateInterpolator());
```

i searched about Interpolator and also i found some links for example this

> [How to apply easing animation function on view in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22896605/how-to-apply-easing-animation-function-on-view-in-android)

what is a my goal.i want to receive  Material Design same animation.i mean this material animation

> https://www.google.com/design/spec/animation/authentic-motion.html#authentic-motion-mass-weight

p.s
my code working perfect but i have spead problem.spead is slowly.i changed durrections but i want to change(Increas) spead  with Interpolator.meybe i have something wrong in this line

```
 return (float) (6 * Math.pow(x, 2) - 8 * Math.pow(x, 3) + 3 * Math.pow(x, 4));
```

My goal is to create leftright animation same Material Design
if anyone knows solution please help me
thanks everyone

Comment: Do you really need a custom `Interpolator`? Material design pages present some standard ones (`AccelerateInterpolator` and `DecelerateInterpolator`).

Comment: yes yes i want custom Interpolator. can  you show me some examples ? @BartoszLipinski Lipinski

Comment: But WHY do you need a custom one? you can use one of the standard ones (e.g. `AccelerateInterpolator` and `DecelerateInterpolator`), they will probably fit your needs.

Comment: I have  LeftToRight Animation and  i want to use  animation same as material design. I mean,in material design   animation has different  spead,i mean,firs time spead is slow and then faster  please see my links@BartoszLipinski Lipinski

Comment: Can you show me  one example? @BartoszLipinski Lipinski

Comment: `anim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());`

Comment: that's all @BartoszLipinski Lipinski